# Elend und Not - der Unterschied

Tags: difference, synonym

> **Elend**: Armut, Not
>
> **Not**: Mangel an lebenswichtigen Dingen; Elend, äußerste Armut

Gibt es denn einen Unterschied zwischen diesen zwei Wörtern?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Not* ist mit dem englischen "need" verwandt und bezeichnet den Mangel an Gütern bzw. materiellen und/oder immateriellen Ressourcen. Not kann vorübergehend sein und sich nur auf ein bestimmtes Gut beziehen. Nur dann, wenn die Not andauert und sich in größerem Umfang auf Güter bezieht, die zu dem jeweiligen Lebensstandard nötig sind, der dafür als Maßstab genommen wird, sprechen wir von "Armut". "In Not geraten" oder "in großer Not sein" betont speziell eine Differenz zwischen früheren, besseren Lebensverhältnissen und einer akuten, meist materiellen Notlage.

*Elend* bedeutete ursprünglich das zwangsweise Leben fern der Heimat, ohne Wurzeln und Aussicht, zurückzukehren. Heute ist es gleichbedeutend mit dem englischen "misery" und kann in unterschiedlichen Kontexten Not, Armut, Verwahrlosung, große Traurigkeit etc. bedeuten. Meist subsumiert der Begriff eine Kombination aus diesen Zuständen und hat eine allgemeinere Bedeutung, meist bezieht er sich auch auf eine Gruppe von Menschen bzw. Lebewesen.

Answer (score 5):

In bestimmten Situationen kann *Elend* m.E. auch auf die Würdelosigkeit eines Verhaltens oder Zustands abzielen. So könnte man z.B. über jemanden, der/die nichts mit sich anzufangen weiß und den ganzen Tag nur noch fernsieht, sagen:

> Es ist ein Elend mit ihm/ihr.

Not oder körperliche Verwahrlosung muss dabei nicht gegeben sein. *Not* würde als Ausdruck hierzu auch nicht passen.